# omcljs basic tutorial giving error: Uncaught Error: Assert failed: No target specified to om.core/root (not (nil? target))

Tags: clojure, om

I am attempting [om's basic tutorial](https://github.com/omcljs/om/wiki/Basic-Tutorial), and run into an error even before changing any code.

I followed the instructions, running `lein new figwheel om-tut -- --om`, `cd om-tut`, and `lein figwheel`.

`http://localhost:3449/` then displays the html text, not the app-state text which it should be displaying instead. Furthermore, when I open my dev tools to the console I see the error message shown in the following screenshot.

[image]

This is unexpected because I have not changed the tutorial at all, just downloaded and run following the instructions to a T. It is also unexpected because the tutorial seemed to work for me just yesterday, running on my same machine.

Any one know what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really old bug in the om.root https://github.com/swannodette/mies-om/issues/2. It should have been fixed by now.